# How to run Command Prompt commands from VB.NET?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have an application which build in vb.net.I never learn VB.I have worked on C#.net.when I run it's setup and execute it,I able to see command prompt.But when I using this application for scheduling task/creating task and scheduling, unable to see command prompt.

I am using following code that create process.

```
Dim Cw As New ProcessStartInfo(name, name & " " & name)
Cw.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized
Process.Start(Cw)
```

Is there is any other way to do this?Without making a process can I execute shell program?I am working on windows8 opeating system

Comment: This question is not clear at all. First thing to note is that this code runs a given program with certain arguments (e.g., Notepad or Chrome or any other application in the computer); so you might be calling that program wrongly. Additionally, it is not clear why you need to execute an external program from an ASP.NET application at all. The .NET Framework is very comprehensive and ASP.NET should be able to take care of almost anything internally (+ JavaScript codes + external libraries added to the project). You should provide more information to help us know about the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simply Shell command, so:

```
Shell(path_to_your_exe, AppWinStyle.MaximizedFocus, true, 1000)
```

Be careful with path, if you have blanks escape they so

```
Shell(""d:\folder blank\my.exe"")
```

MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question, you might be using a Windows Form Application and you want to see the command line info of your external application.

In that case, you can use this code:

```
Sub Main()

    Dim ProcessStartInfo = BuildProcessStartInfo("E:\path\to\your\exeFile.exe", "")
    Dim proc = Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo)

End Sub

Public Function BuildProcessStartInfo(exeFilePath As String, arguments As String) As ProcessStartInfo

    Dim startInfo = New ProcessStartInfo
    startInfo.FileName = exeFilePath
    startInfo.Arguments = arguments
    startInfo.CreateNoWindow = False
    startInfo.UseShellExecute = True
    startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized

    Return startInfo

End Function
```